# I want month in three alphabet format but MMM is returning month number with "M" at beginning in iOS UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter, uidatepicker

This is my method which gets executed when UIDatePicker time is selected:

```
-(void) datePickerAction: (UIDatePicker *)sender {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy"];
    self.dateTextView.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.datePicker.date];
}
```

This gives me date as `Tue M09 29 10:26:29 GMT+05:30 2015`

I want my month to appear in three alphabet format like OCT or JAN.
Surprisingly, if i comment line `[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]];` then i get month in correct way as `Tue Sep 29 10:26:29 Indian Standard Time 2015` with same date formatter. Please tell me where I am going wrong.

My desired date format example is `Tue Sep 29 10:26:29 GMT+05:30 2015`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got little idea on the root cause of my problem after reading to [Amin Negm-Awad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32836164/4618125). So, I implemented a work around and it is working perfectly fine in my situation. For getting my date in my desired format, I decided to use two `NSDateFormatter` with different locale and then I appended string from both the formatter to get desired results.

For getting month in three letter month, I made a `NSDateFormatter` object 
and set it's locale as `[NSLocale currentLocale]` this gave me month name in three letter format.

For getting GMT, I made another `NSDateFormtter` object and set it's locale as `[NSLocale systemLocale]` and this gave me GMT format.

After this, I appended both the strings and I got desired results. Complete modified code given below:

```
-(void) datePickerAction: (UIDatePicker *)sender {
    [self.datePicker setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];

    NSDateFormatter *dayMonthDate = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [dayMonthDate setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    [dayMonthDate setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss"];

    NSDateFormatter *gmtAndYearFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [gmtAndYearFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]];
    [gmtAndYearFormatter setDateFormat:@"zzzz yyyy"];

    self.dateTextView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",
                              [dayMonthDate stringFromDate:self.datePicker.date],
                              [gmtAndYearFormatter stringFromDate:self.datePicker.date]];
}
```

So, I got result as `Tue Sep 29 11:58:29 GMT+05:30 2015`

Answer (score 1):

`MMM` does not format a 3 letter abbreviation. You get an abbreviation, but what  it is, depends on the locale. The official Unicode documentation has an example with a 4(!) letter abbreviation ("Sept"):

http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date%5FFormat%5FPatterns

So what you get depends on the locale. Since `+systemLocale` delivers "no locale", …

> Use the system locale when you don’t want any localizations.

… I suppose that `NSDateFormatter` simply has no idea to create a month abbreviation without locale information. And even this would be possible, it would be pointless, because what should a localized form without locale should be? Swahili month names with indian abbreviations?

Likely you want to use `+currentLocale`, which is the user setting on the device.

Comment: I tried using `+currentLocale` and it is giving me `Tue Sep 29 10:26:29 Indian Standard Time 2015`. My desired date format example is `Tue Sep 29 10:26:29 GMT+05:30 2015`. I am badly stuck at this point.

Comment: Negam-Awad I figured out a work around. Thank you as your answer gave me clear idea and I could find a work around solution through that!

Answer (score 1):

It is better to create one Function so you can easily way to access and what you have to return.

e.g.

```
-(NSString *)getStringFromMonth:(NSString *)strMonth
{
    NSInteger monthNum = [strMonth integerValue];
    switch (monthNum)
    {
        case 1:
            return @"Jan";
            break;
        case 2:
            return @"Feb";
            break;
        case 3:
            return @"Mar";
            break;
        case 4:
            return @"Apr";
            break;
        case 5:
            return @"May";
            break;
        case 6:
            return @"Jun";
            break;
        case 7:
            return @"Jul";
            break;
        case 8:
            return @"Aug";
            break;
        case 9:
            return @"Sep";
            break;
        case 10:
            return @"Oct";
            break;
        case 11:
            return @"Nov";
            break;
        case 12:
            return @"Dec";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return strMonth;
}
```